# Как запросом определить нарушение последовательности?

Tags: sql, алгоритм, oracle, числовые-последовательности

Есть последовательность записей, у которых в поле А записаны числа. Нормальный вид этой последовательности - непрерывная (1, 2, 3, 4, 5).

Как определить с помощью запроса, нарушена ли последовательность или нет?

Пример нарушения последовательности: (1, 2, 4, 5, 7), либо (1, 2, 2, 3, 4).

Думал как-то через факториал подойти к решению, но не осилил. Может есть у кого-то соображения по поводу решения?

---

PS Предложеный дубликат не учитывает повторяющиеся значения.

Comment: Возможный дубликат вопроса: [Как найти пропуски в последовательности чисел?](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1152865/%d0%9a%d0%b0%d0%ba-%d0%bd%d0%b0%d0%b9%d1%82%d0%b8-%d0%bf%d1%80%d0%be%d0%bf%d1%83%d1%81%d0%ba%d0%b8-%d0%b2-%d0%bf%d0%be%d1%81%d0%bb%d0%b5%d0%b4%d0%be%d0%b2%d0%b0%d1%82%d0%b5%d0%bb%d1%8c%d0%bd%d0%be%d1%81%d1%82%d0%b8-%d1%87%d0%b8%d1%81%d0%b5%d0%bb)

Comment: Последовательность всегда начинается с единицы? Тогда тупо сравниваем ROW_NUMBER() и id.

Comment: может сделать выборку в курсор и проверять, что предыдущая запись отличается от текущей на 1

Comment: Нет, последовательность начинается с 0. Нужно использовать только sql. Может аналитической функцией lag кстати?

Comment: LAG не подойдёт - она не различает дубликаты.

Comment: @MaxU ТС скорее всего прав - _Предложеный дубликат не учитывает повторяющиеся значения_, он слишком "специализированный", чтобы под него эту тему закрыть.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> последовательность начинается с 0 – Анатолий Эрнст

```
WITH cte AS ( SELECT number, ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY number) - 1 rn
              FROM table )
SELECT EXISTS ( SELECT NULL
                FROM cte
                WHERE number <> rn ) AS not_consecutive
```

Answer (score 3):

Разница между текушим значением последовательности и порядковым номером записи всегда одно и тоже число, неважно с какого числа начинается отсчёт. Если в результате несколько таких чисел, то где-то есть нарушение последовательности.

Рабочий пример:

```sql
with t (seq, num) as (
    select 'seq1', column_value from sys.odciNumberList (1, 2, 3, 4, 5) n union all  
    select 'seq2', column_value from sys.odciNumberList (1, 2, 4, 5, 7) n union all  
    select 'seq3', column_value from sys.odciNumberList (1, 2, 2, 3, 4) n union all  
    select 'seq4', column_value from sys.odciNumberList (0, 1, 2, 3, 4) n
) 
select seq, case when count (distinct grp)=1 then 'yes' else 'no' end consecutive
from (
    select seq, num - row_number() over (partition by seq order by num) grp
    from t)
group by seq
order by seq
```

Результат:

```
SEQ  CONSECUTIVE 
---- ------------
seq1 yes         
seq2 no          
seq3 no          
seq4 yes
```

Если версия 12c и выше, то задачу можно решить с клаузой `MATCH_RECOGNIZE`:

```
select seq, case when count (*)=1 then 'yes' else 'no'end consecutive
from t
match_recognize (
    partition by seq
    order by num
    measures null grp 
    pattern (a b*)
    define b as num = prev (num)+1
) group by seq;

SEQ  CONSECUTIVE 
---- ------------
seq1 yes         
seq2 no          
seq3 no          
seq4 yes
```